# How to log/see on intermediate value inside a loop or continuous input only once

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes, when debugging, I want to log/see the content of a variable - inside a for loop - only once. The same can happen when I am dealing with a stream of input. Is there a way to do that in Python. I want to avoid logging the variable content at each iteration or when new input comes in at a later point in time. I want to avoid using a boolean flag. Just wondering if there is module that provides the same function. Thanks!

A potential scenario - I want to see what's stored in outDict after the first sample is processed:

```
for sample in manySamples:
    outDict = {}
    flag = process(sample,outDict) //function process sample and saves result in outDict
    if flag:
        #rest of the code
```

Comment: Do you have an example situation? Based on what you are describing a conditional seems to be the best approach, but it's hard to say without the context of when you would want to use this.

Comment: Updated my post with a potential scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Is it ok to put a breakpoint at 4'th line of your code and run program with debug mode?

Comment: I was hoping to generate a log file instead of running it in debug mode. If the program must run continuously, one idea could be to use a counter and every time counter % step == 0 we can write the result in a log file. I was hoping to get better solutions from the community.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if you want to do it based on the iteration value is through `enumerate()`, let's say you wanted to check the value of every 3rd iteration you could do:

```py
for counter, sample in enumerate(manySamples):
    outDict = {}
    flag = process(sample,outDict) # function process sample and saves result in outDict
    if counter % 3 == 0: # If the counter is a multiple of 3
        # Here you would put the logging code for whatever values are relevant
    if flag:
        #rest of the code
```

Since I don't know the full context of this code, this may be better in your situation since it looks like you're using `flag` to delimit useful values:

```py
for counter, sample in enumerate(manySamples):
    outDict = {}
    flag = process(sample,outDict) # function process sample and saves result in outDict

    if flag:
            if counter % 3 == 0: # If the counter is a multiple of 3
            # Here you would put the logging code for whatever values are relevant
    # rest of the code
```